# C# - How to draw a chart with 3 variables(Position[32], ByteValue[255], Frequency[int])

Tags: c#, graph, charts, frequency

I want to draw a graph showing the Frequency of Byte-Values ocurred in each Position.

//Pos[32][Result[255][Frequency[int]

`Dictionary<UInt16, Dictionary<UInt16, int>>` // I want to draw this

Comment: MSChart is really bad at this. But, if one of your dimensions can do with only a __few__ values  you can use its 3D options and __add a series for each of the z-values__. If you explain your variables better and maybe add an image of what you need I can show you how. As it stands the question is not well-written and too broad. - An alternative could be painting points if different colors to mimic z as color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

MSChart not very good at this.

But, if one of your dimensions can do with only a **few distinct** values, you can use its 3D options and add one series for each of the z-values.

I assume you have 32 positions only and chose this dimension as the z-axis.

MSChart doesn't really have a z-axis property; but if 3D is enbled for a `ChartArea` the `Series` are used as a 3rd dimension. So I add 32 Series..

Then I loop over 256 values and create a frequency value more or less randomly.

Here is the code for the above result:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.Series.Clear();
    SeriesChartType type = SeriesChartType.Point;
    Random rnd = new Random(1);

    ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];

    ca.Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
    ca.Area3DStyle.PointGapDepth = 500;
    ca.Area3DStyle.PointDepth = 500;

    for (int p = 0; p < 32; p++)
    {
        Series s = chart1.Series.Add("P" + p);
        s.ChartType = type;

        for (int v = 0; v < 256; v++)
        {
            // test data
            int f = 25+(int)(rnd.Next(5) + 10*Math.Sin((p * (256 - v )/ 100f)));
            s.Points.AddXY(v, f);
        }
    }
}
```

To rotate I used this common click event for all buttons:

```
private void btn_rotate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int step = 10;
    ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
    if (sender == btn_reset) { ca.Area3DStyle.Rotation = 30;  ca.Area3DStyle.Inclination = 30; } 
    if (sender == btn_left && ca.Area3DStyle.Rotation < 180-step) ca.Area3DStyle.Rotation+= step;
    if (sender == btn_right && ca.Area3DStyle.Rotation > -180-step) ca.Area3DStyle.Rotation-= step;
    if (sender == btn_down && ca.Area3DStyle.Inclination < 90-step) ca.Area3DStyle.Inclination+= step;
    if (sender == btn_up && ca.Area3DStyle.Inclination > -90-step) ca.Area3DStyle.Inclination-= step;
}
```